# Two servers two forms and one database

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

Hello I have two servers, one with a form and mysql database that I insert data into the database. The other server has only a form that I want the data that I fill into the form to be inserted into the firsts database server's.
What's the way to insert the from seconde sever's form into the database securely?

This is first server's code:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <link rel="" href="">

  
</head>

<body>
  <script src=""></script>
  
  <form action="reg.php" method="post">
  <label>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  <label>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
 if(empty($_POST["firstname"]) OR empty($_POST["lastname"]) ) {
  header( "refresh:5; url=registration.html" );
  echo "please fill all the fields.";
 }
 else {
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","form");
  if(!$con) {
   die(" error: ". mysql_error());
  }
  $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname=$_POST['llastname'];
  $sql= "INSERT INTO a_database (id, firstname, lastname,)
  VALUES('DEFAULT','$firstname','$lastname',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
   echo "success";
  }
  else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
  
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP code of your second server, you just need to change the database address:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("<first server address>","root","","form");
```

Then, check your firewall rules (MySQL uses port 3306 by default) and MySQL configuration on the first server to allow remote SQL connection from the second server.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple you have to just put value of "action" attribute is path where the server side script is running.

You have to just make sure <form action="http://yourdomain.com/reg.php" method="post" > is same for both form

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <link rel="" href="">

  
</head>

<body>
  <script src=""></script>
  
  <form action="http://yourdomain.com/reg.php" method="post">
  <label>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  <label>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```